# How to properly configure ffmpeg for the Go wrapper

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I've been trying out the wrapper for ffmpeg written in Go ([imkira/go-libav](https://github.com/imkira/go-libav/)) and tried to follow the example, but after a successful build I've got an error that the decoder can't be found.
This is the part of code where the error occurs:

```
if ctx.decStream = firstStream(ctx.decFmt); ctx.decStream == nil {
  log.Fatalf("Couldn't find a video stream.")
}

codecCtx := ctx.decStream.CodecContext()
codec := avcodec.FindDecoderByID(codecCtx.CodecID())
if codec == nil {
  log.Fatalf("Could not find decoder: %v\n", codecCtx.CodecID())
}
```

The `first_stream` function:

```
func firstStream(fmtCtx *avformat.Context) *avformat.Stream {
  for _, stream := range fmtCtx.Streams() {
    switch stream.CodecContext().CodecType() {
      case avutil.MediaTypeVideo:
        return stream
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

That's the same as in the example, which also has the same problem. I assume it isn't code-based but I can't figure it out. I tried registering all formats but actually it happens in the `init()` function.
I'm using Manjaro Linux 19.0.0 and have FFmpeg 3.3.9 installed from source.

Comment: What decoder name are you trying to use? are you using a ffmpeg built that has support for it? maybe try the cli tools like ffprobe and ffmpeg from the same build and try to transcode?

Comment: The source video is encoded in MPEG4, but I also tried another file which is in H.264. Both doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know which decoder ffmpeg tries to use? i get a feeling it can probe which codec but has no valid decode to use etc. ffmpeg 3.3.9 is quite old also. Possible to try newer version?

Comment: How would I know? It can't find any decoder to use, and I only see their IDs. Can't tell now, but they don't tell anything, it is the decoder ID based on the stream information retrieved with FFmpeg itself. The version is quite old, but otherwise it doesn't compile, and still the example was tested with the same h.264 file I used later.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it from the command line, it works just fine.

Comment: Ok, strange. Wonder if you can iterate and print out all codecs supported somehow? what is the codecs id btw?

Comment: I just iterated over numbers from 0 to 500k to see which decoders can be found for them and got a bunch of results., including popular ones. Now I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: Does any of the id:s match the one that is says it can't find? look at the 3.3 code it should end up in this loop https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/libavcodec_2utils_8c_source.html#l03131 ... there is some conditions there. Maybe try set a breakpoint with gdb as step thru?